# How get core get current user info?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, ldap

how get current logged user on windows pc in new .net core framework ?

Old namespace

```
System.DirectoryServices;
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
```

not implemented yeat :(
Advise the ported library novell.ldap but I still do not understand how to get information about the user.

I get short name from `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`
how get full name ? Example "Mary Ann"

Answer (score 0):

First, ASP.NET Core can run on Linux and Mac, where you have no "Windows" user at all.

But even if you will run you app on Windows only - what user you mean? If your website is running on server behind IIS - than IIS is started as a service, without any interactive user, and your app also started under some service account.

But if you will run your app only under Windows and only interactively (user will start `dotnet run` or similar) then easiest way - read environment variables `USERDOMAIN` and `USERNAME`. In command prompt run `set` and you will see all environment variables currently defined in your session. You may read them via `Environment` class or add to `ConfigurationBuilder` with `AddEnvironmentVariables()` in `Startup.cs`.

Comment: only windows user

Comment: Do not know ASP.NT, but you may be able to use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPNEGO  to obtain the information assuming the LDAP implementation supports such actions. (ie NOT just Windows).